# How to add dynamic rows for each day in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

How to add dynamic rows for each day with the processor name as Tom, activity as Login, Quarter Hour as 7:15:00AM and activity duration as 25200? The same details should be added for each day of the month except weekends.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try and keep all data entry at the source i.e. do this in your ETL process. Power BI was not designed for this.